# Getting a POST requests require a Content-length header response(411 error)

Tags: php, http, youtube, youtube-api

I have been trying to upload video on video on you tube using my own code.
During one step when i try to upload videos meta data on you tube to get the token and url for the video to upload i get a

> POST requests require a Content-length header. That’s all we know.
>   (411)

My code is as follows:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
              <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
                xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
                xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
                <media:group>
                  <media:title type="plain">Video.loc</media:title>
                  <media:description type="plain">
                    Video.loc first vid
                  </media:description>
                  <media:category
                    scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">People
                  </media:category>
                  <media:keywords>Video.loc</media:keywords>
                </media:group>
              </entry>';
    $headers = array('Authorization: AuthSub token="'.$_SESSION['AuthSubSessToken'],
                      'GData-Version: 2',
                     'X-GData-Key: key='.$key,
                     'Content-length:'.strlen($xml),
                     'Content-Type:application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8'
                );
      $curl = curl_init('http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken');

              curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
              curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
              curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
              $response = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($curl));                                 
              $response = curl_exec($curl);

              $arrToken = explode('=',$response);
              print('<pre>');print_r($arrToken);die();
              curl_close($curl)
```

Does any one knows that if it is error on my side or on the google?.

Regards
Himanshu Sharma

Comment: Kindly help me.It is boggling my mind here.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing `"` after

```
  AuthSub token="'.$_SESSION['AuthSubSessToken'],
```

that might be messing up the headers.